# Temporary freeze at login screen after suspend

Tags: suspend, freeze

I'm currently dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Windows 8.1. On Ubuntu, when I wake up my system after a suspend, I'm taken to the login screen, as I'd expect. However, the system is consistently unresponsive for a period of time ranging roughly between 16 and 24 seconds. During this period, I am unable to move the cursor or to enter anything using the keyboard. After the unresponsive period, I am able to move the cursor and interact with the system using the keyboard normally; also, if I type during the unresponsive period, up to 5 characters will appear in the password field once the system resumes normal function (if I typed x characters during the unresponsive period, then if x<5, x characters will appear. Otherwise, 5 characters will appear). What might be causing this behaviour, and how can I fix it?

A copy of my pm-suspend.log and Xorg.0.log files, and the output of `sudo dmesg` can be found here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1YKLXOjqaPATWR6VGF2WDJlZ2s&usp=sharing

Comment: Could it be related to disks spinning up?

Comment: That's possible. How would I go about investigating whether that's the issue? Note, though, that on Windows 8.1 my system is responsive after suspend with virtually no unresponsive period. Wouldn't I expect similar behaviour on Windows 8.1 if it were my hard drive causing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/532799/edit) your question to include or  link to copies of the files `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and the output of `sudo dmesg` just after resuming from suspension? They should contain relevant info about your problem.

Comment: Maybe you can listen to the disks making different noises when spinning up? It should not block, certainly, independent of whether it's related to disks - but would be good to know as a start.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel At the point when I resume my system, I only hear the fan spinning up, but about 0.5s before the system becomes responsive again, I am able to hear a short burst of hard drive activity. This behaviour seems to be repeatable.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have attached the requested files. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [dmesg output](https://doc-0c-1k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/8gv7qc73amq6scjjgc6trtt6esf6ac0u/1412596800000/15614420742611996759/*/0B1YKLXOjqaPAVXlyN3lQWFpxVlE?h=16653014193614665626&e=download) there's a bug in the WiFi driver.

Let's take a closer look: the most recent wakeup event is at

```
[22500.127146] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
```

and the wakeup finishes ~5 s later:

```
[22505.833530] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

The system then takes another ~5s to re-initiate the PS/2 interface (for keyboard and touch pad):

```
[22507.823851] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[22515.585161] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
```

When it tries to re-initiate the WiFi, there are 3 subsequent traces of identical errors in the WiFi subsystem over the course of ~10s:

```
[22918.219140] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
[22918.219460] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
[22920.320875] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[22920.323141] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[22920.323145] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[22920.323148] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[22920.323149] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[22920.323151] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[22920.323152] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[22920.323154] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[22923.987050] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[22923.987110] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 484 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/net/wireless/sme.c:797 cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90 [cfg80211]()
[22923.987113] Modules linked in: michael_mic arc4 dm_crypt rfcomm bnep bluetooth microread_mei microread mei_phy crc_ccitt hci nfc binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm uvcvideo lib80211_crypt_tkip videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_core videodev snd_rawmidi crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_seq_device cryptd snd_timer joydev serio_raw wl(POF) lib80211 cfg80211 snd rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick soundcore mei_me mei parport_pc ppdev nls_iso8859_1 sony_laptop lp parport mac_hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse i915 ahci r8169 libahci rtsx_pci mii i2c_algo_bit video drm_kms_helper drm
[22923.987211] CPU: 0 PID: 484 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: PF       W  O 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu
[22923.987216] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVF15A1C5E/VAIO, BIOS R0220DA 11/18/2013
[22923.987220]  0000000000000009 ffff88023fa0bd88 ffffffff8171e320 0000000000000000
[22923.987228]  ffff88023fa0bdc0 ffffffff8106775d ffff8800a6e1a000 ffff8800a37bdf80
[22923.987235]  000000000000006a ffff88003398c700 0000000000000001 ffff88023fa0bdd0
[22923.987241] Call Trace:
[22923.987254]  [<ffffffff8171e320>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[22923.987263]  [<ffffffff8106775d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[22923.987270]  [<ffffffff8106783a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[22923.987298]  [<ffffffffa024a509>] cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90 [cfg80211]
[22923.987374]  [<ffffffffa0416528>] wl_bss_connect_done.isra.21+0x98/0x1a0 [wl]
[22923.987441]  [<ffffffffa041682c>] wl_notify_connect_status+0x1fc/0x410 [wl]
[22923.987504]  [<ffffffffa0415135>] wl_event_handler+0x55/0x220 [wl]
[22923.987566]  [<ffffffffa04150e0>] ? wl_get_assoc_ies+0x240/0x240 [wl]
[22923.987574]  [<ffffffff8108b4a2>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[22923.987581]  [<ffffffff8108b3d0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
[22923.987588]  [<ffffffff8172ecbc>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[22923.987594]  [<ffffffff8108b3d0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
[22923.987599] ---[ end trace a8bec1fd8bc015b5 ]---
```

The system typically freezes while it recovers from kernel errors (if possible), so this would explain the freeze-up you see. I recommend that you [file a bug report against the Broadcom driver package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+filebug), include the `dmesg` output, and maybe link to this answer. They know better how to help you and bugs are off topic on AU. [Edit] There's a similar bug already: [Broadcom Sta/wl Drivers causes (more) kernel panic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1315912).

If you want to poke around more, you can try to (temporarily) disable the WiFi subsystem to see, if the problem persists. The bug may be fixed in newer kernels and/or driver versions. You can try out the most recent (until yesterday) kernel series 3.16 with the package `linux-generic-lts-utopic` from the [Canonical Kernel Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty). The repositories for the upcoming Ubuntu Utopic contain a [newer version of the Broadcom WiFi driver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1).

[Edit] [A commenter to a similar bug on the RPM Fusion bug tracker](https://bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3136#c6) suggests to manually set your radio frequency spectrum regulation area in the module parameters (replace `EU` with one of `US` or `JP` depending on your region):

```sh
sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf > /dev/null <<< 'options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom="EU"'
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```